# How do I keep all quick menu settings active, even when setting is disabled on Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: gnome-shell, 18.10

I find the quick menu (or however it's called) a great tool to quickly enable or disable some things:

[image]
<sup>(click to enlarge)</sup>

However, if i were to say, disable Bluetooth, it disappears from the menu! Is there any way to show all, or selected settings in that menu? Bluetooth, Nightlight, etc.